# How to send parameter by view

Tags: laravel

I send the parameter by url in view but I get an error of the undefined variable but I don't understand why if I am not sent that variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pafv.png)

**web.php**

```
Route::get('acceso/{url}', 'AccesoController@index')->name('acceso');
Route::put('acceso/user-id/{url}', 'AccesoController@update');
```

**acceso.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('acceso/user-id', ['url' => $url]) }}">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')
 <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Bienvenido a Suprapp, {{ old('title', $acceso->name) }}</h1>
 <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Acceso a la APP</button>
 <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2020</p>
</form>
```

**AccesoController.php**

```
public function index($url)
{
    $users = User::where('url', $url)->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        return view('acceso', ['url' => $user->id]);
    }
    
    
}

public function update(Request $request, $url)
{
    //$data = $request->all();
    $user = User::find($url);

    $user->ip_acceso = $request->ip(); 
    $user->url = $request->url(); 
    
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('login', ['url' => $user->id]);
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is causing your problem:

```
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Bienvenido a Suprapp, {{ old('title', $acceso->name) }}</h1>
```

You're using a variable `$accesso` but do not pass it through when you return your view.

```
public function index($url)
{
    $users = User::where('url', $url)->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        return view('acceso', ['url' => $user->id]); // no accesso passed
    }  
}
```

Comment: how do i print the name

Comment: Pass `$acceso` to your view from your function? What are you trying to print the name of?

Comment: `<h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Bienvenido a Suprapp, {{ old('title', '
here print the name') }}</h1>
`

Comment: @user947840 Sorry, but that still doesn't help me answer how to print the name as you've not told us where `name` is coming from. If it is a property on `$acceso` then pass `$acceso` into your view as you do with `$url`.